# Checking for permutations of a space-containing string in java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, spaces

How would I check to ensure that a string does not contain any permutations of the space character in Java?

i.e., I want to check if my string equals `""`, `" "`, `"  "`, etc.

I do not want to just check if my string contains a space, because if I had a string `"My code works"`, it should not be parsed. I want to check only for strings that contain exclusively spaces, and no letters or other characters whatsoever.

Is this possible to do in a single if-statement?

Comment: suppose you can use `String input = "  ";boolean retval = input.contains(" ");` to check whether input contains spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) with the pattern `\s*`.  This pattern will match empty string or any amount of continuous whitespace.

```
String input = "   ";
if (input.matches("\\s*")) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you can also use [StringUtils.isBlank(aString)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) provided by apache commons.

```
 Checks if a CharSequence is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

 StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
 StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("  ")      = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
 StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```

Answer (score 1):

one more way

```
if(input.trim().length() == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me:

```
for (i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    string = string.get(i).replaceAll(" ", "");
}

if (string.equals("")) {
    //do something
}
```